# Windows Server 2008 R2 equal to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008-r2

HI!

My Windows 7 RC is destroying itself in some days.

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Dreamspark License.

Well, I ask myself can I use the server like my Windows 7?

Are there some **performance decreases** or **other issues**?

I want to use the server for playing and developing.

What I already seen is a list of Games that run with no problems.

Comment: There is nothing directly about development (or development tools) here: should be on Super User.

Comment: As Richard said, I believe this question should have been posted on Super User instead.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not know superuser :) I googled it now. Cool site =) Do they belong together or do they have the same developer origin?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can do it without problems. The only difference I know is that windows server can handle more connections than windows 7, and it is optimized for that, but as a personal SSOO it should work OK

Answer (score 1):

A server OS may be more optimized for background tasks (but that is something you can configure I think.)  But it should not be any problems developing on a server.

Answer (score 0):

In previous iterations of Windows there were problems using client versions for some types of development (e.g. IIS on WinXP didn't support multiple web sites).

Such limitations have reduced over time.

Unless you specifically need something in 2008R2 that is not in 7, go with 7.